# ASP.NET MVC format a JSON response from a dynamic

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, dynamic

I am using Dapper to return a `IEnumerable<dynamic>` object with the signature of:

```
date: 01/01/2011
VarName = "VariableX"
VariableValue = "Value 1"

date: 01/01/2011
VarName = "VariableY"
VariableValue = "Value 2"
```

I am looking to turn this into a JSON response of:

```
{ date: 01/01/2011
 VariableX: Value 1
 VariableY: Value 2
}
```

..etc and would appreciate any points on where to start from!

Thanks

EDIT:

If I flatten out the object as its returned I see:

```
[
{"date":"\/Date(1331683206000)\/","VariableName":"Variable1","VariableValue":"ValueX"},
{"date":"\/Date(1331683206000)\/","VariableName":"Variable2","VariableValue":"ValueY"},
{"date":"\/Date(1331683206000)\/","VariableName":"Variable3","VariableValue":"ValueZ"}
]
```

What I am essentially looking for guidance on is how to flip it out so it reads:

```
[
{"date":"\/Date(1331683206000)\/","Variable1","ValueX"},
{"date":"\/Date(1331683206000)\/","Variable2","ValueY"},
{"date":"\/Date(1331683206000)\/","Variable3","ValueZ"},
]
```

EDIT #2: Fixed required output to:

```
[
    {
        "date": "/Date(1331683206000)/",
        "Variable1": "ValueX"
    },
    {
        "date": "/Date(1331683206000)/",
        "Variable2": "ValueY"
    },
    {
        "date": "/Date(1331683206000)/",
        "Variable3": "ValueZ"
    }
]
```

EDIT #3:

```
{
        "date": "/Date(1331683206000)/",
        "Variable1": "ValueX",
        "Variable2": "ValueY",
        "Variable3": "ValueZ"
    },
{
        "date": "/Date(1431683206000)/",
        "Variable1": "ValueX",
        "Variable2": "ValueY",
        "Variable3": "ValueZ"
    },
{
        "date": "/Date(151683206000)/",
        "Variable1": "ValueX",
        "Variable2": "ValueY",
        "Variable3": "ValueZ"
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. What is missing currently is what code you have tried so far and what difficulties did you encounter with it.

Comment: Thanks - I've added a bit more information

Comment: Alright, now it's more clear. What you are trying to achieve is impossible because what you have shown is invalid JSON.

Comment: My mistake, pasted the wrong format, please see Edit 2

Comment: Alright, now that makes sense. I have updated my answer to illustrate how you could project your collection to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I am essentially looking for guidance on is how to flip it out so it reads:

```
[
    {"date":"\/Date(1331683206000)\/","Variable1","ValueX"},
    {"date":"\/Date(1331683206000)\/","Variable2","ValueY"},
    {"date":"\/Date(1331683206000)\/","Variable3","ValueZ"}
]
```

I am afraid that this is impossible because your desired output is an **invalid** JSON.

If you meant this:

```
[
    ["\/Date(1331683206000)\/","Variable1","ValueX"],
    ["\/Date(1331683206000)\/","Variable2","ValueY"],
    ["\/Date(1331683206000)\/","Variable3","ValueZ"]
]
```

then this is an entirely different matter.

---

UPDATE:

After showing your actual desired JSON you could project your result in order to achieve it:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> result = ....
var viewModel = result.Select(x =>
{
    var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    result["date"] = x.date;
    result[x.VariableName] = x.VariableValue;
    return result;
}).ToList();
return Json(viewModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Thanks - thinking forward, would it be possible to group the variables by date to have them represent my edit #3?

Comment: In your update #3 you have shown a single javascript object, not an array. What if you have 2 different dates in the input? What would be your desired output?

Comment: If there was another date period it would show display another JSON  group so esentially grouping on distinct date for all variable combinations - I've updated my edit

Comment: Thanks for your help Darin, I will try to condense the JSON slightly by grouping by date on the initial select - thanks again.